# Где студия хранит строку для NuGet package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, settings

Код хранится на отдельном диске. После переустановки системы и восстановления всех программ студия выдала кучу ошибок:

The package Autofac with version 3.5.2 could not be found in C:\Users\Artur\.nuget\packages.
Run a NuGet package restore to download the package.

Пользователя Artur уже нет, как объяснить студии, что путь теперь другой?

Comment: [Restore packages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные хранятся в папке .vs (где студия хранит все настройки по решению), а также в папках */bin, */obj в каждой папке каждого проекта.

Решение проблемы:

Полагаю, что достаточно удалить папку .vs. Я удалил все что находилось в .gitignore с помощью SourceTree.

После студия долго все заново качает и успешно собирает проект.

Совет Alexander Petrov к сожелению не помог.